# Generate ipa without paid apple developer account

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, provisioning-profile, hockeyapp

Can we generate ipa from Xcode without paid apple developer account? I want to share ipa so that it can be installed on any of the iPhone.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No, unless the iphones are jailbroken, you cannot run unsigned code on iOS devices.  There's not way to generate a signed IPA for iOS without a developer account.  A free developer account will allow you to build an app that will run for 7 days on a pre-defined set of devices (you would need to register any devices on which you want the code to run).

But if you could build and deploy an app without the signing process, developer could bypass the App Store, which is something Apple doesn't want for multiple reasons.