# Generate .ipa file without Apple developer account

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

I'm trying to compile my ionic 3 app to ipa. I use MacInCloud.com. I don't have any Apple Developer account; I just have an AppleID and an iPhone 7 (if that helps).

Now while using XCode in MacInCloud, I clicked `Product > Archive` but then it displays Build Error. Turns out I need an iOS Provisioning Profile. As of now, I couldn't find a way to generate an iOS Provisioning Profile without having a paid Apple Developer account. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570158/generate-ipa-without-paid-apple-developer-account), the answer mentions `A free developer account will allow you to build an app that will run for 7 days on a pre-defined set of devices (you would need to register any devices on which you want the code to run).` but I couldn't find where to do this.

So can I actually generate an ipa file without a paid ios developer account? If no, is it possible for me to have someone generate a provisioning profile using their ios developer account for me?

Thanks

**Update:
The methods described in the link in the comments requires me to connect my device. But I'm using MacInCloud.com, so there's no way for me to get Xcode to connect to my device.. at least I don't know how.**

Comment: Did you read the following tutorial from the Ionic blog: [Deploying to a Device without an Apple Developer Account](https://blog.ionicframework.com/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)