# How can build app without paid developer account at apple using xcode 13

Tags: xcode

I have built webview IOS app yet I want to built **ipa** so that iphone users can install it without apple developer account however I am facing this on **Product>Archive** are disabled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5zpB.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53570158/1187415

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't. In order to upload apps to the app store you need a paid developer account.

With a free developer account you can install your test apps on a small number of devices who's UUIDs you register to your account. (I haven't done this, so I'm a bit vague on the details, but that's my understanding.)